# Laravel 5.3 - 500 internal error when saving a new Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When trying to create a new instance of my model `Apartment` I get a `500 (Internal Server Error)`. I have other `/create/` routes that I use to create new instance of my models and they work properly and they're set up same as `ApartmentController@create`, but for some weird reason it doesn't work.

`ApartmentController@create`

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $addresses = Address::all();
    return view('address/create')->with('addresses', $addresses);
}
```

`ApartmentController@store`

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $address = new Address();
    $this->authorize('create', $address);

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'building_number' => 'required|integer',
        'street' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('addresses/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $address->building_number = $request->building_number;
    $address->street = $request->street;

    $address->save();

    return redirect('addresses/create');
}
```

`View apartment/create`

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        @if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ action("ApartmentController@store") }}">
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>Register a new apartment</legend>

                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="address_id">Address</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select id="address_id" name="address_id" class="form-control">
                            @foreach($addresses as $address)
                                <option value="{{$address->id}}">{{$address->street}} {{$address->building_number}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        <span class="help-block">Apartments building number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="apartment_number">Apartment Number</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="apartment_number" name="apartment_number" type="text" placeholder="2402" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">The apartment number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="size">Apartment Size</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="size" name="size" type="text" placeholder="56qm" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">The size of the apartment in qm</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="living_area_size">Living Area Size</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="living_area_size" name="living_area_size" type="text" placeholder="23qm" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                        <span class="help-block">The size of the living area in qm</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Select Basic -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="suitable_for">Suitable For</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select id="suitable_for" name="suitable_for" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="help-block">Number of people the apartment is suitable for.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Select Basic -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="furnished">Furnished</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select id="furnished" name="furnished" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">Yes</option>
                            <option value="0">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Select Basic -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="balcony_or_terrace">Balcony or Terrace</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select id="balcony_or_terrace" name="balcony_or_terrace" class="form-control">
                            <option value="none">None</option>
                            <option value="balcony">Balcony</option>
                            <option value="terrace">Terrace</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Select Basic -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="floor">Floor</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select id="floor" name="floor" class="form-control">
                            <option value="ground">Ground</option>
                            <option value="first">First</option>
                            <option value="second">Second</option>
                            <option value="third">Third</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Textarea -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="description">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <legend>Registered Apartments</legend>
        @foreach($apartments as $apartment)
            <div class="address">
                Apartment {{ $apartment->apartment_number }}

                <a href="{{ url('/apartments/' . $apartment->id . '/edit') }}"
                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                           document.getElementById('edit-form-{{$apartment->id}}').submit();">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
                </a>

                <form id="edit-form-{{$apartment->id}}" action="{{ url('/apartments/' . $apartment->id . '/edit') }}" method="GET" style="display: none;">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="address_id" value="{{$apartment->id}}">
                </form>


                <a href="{{ url('/apartments/' . $apartment->id) }}"
                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                           document.getElementById('delete-form-{{$apartment->id}}').submit();">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button>
                </a>

                <form id="delete-form-{{$apartment->id}}" method="POST" action="/apartments/{{$apartment->id}}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

`Route web.php`

`Route::resource('apartments', 'ApartmentController');`

apartments table for Apartment model
[image: apartments table]

I tried to catch the exception on the `save()` method, but nothing is being caught and I still get redirected to `/apartments` without any Laravel error just Chroms 500 error page.

This is how I tried to catch the error using [dwightwatson/validating](https://github.com/dwightwatson/validating):

```
try{
        $apartment = new Apartment();

        $apartment->apartment_number = $request->apartment_number;
        $apartment->size = $request->size;
        $apartment->living_area_size = $request->living_area_size;
        $apartment->suitable_for = $request->suitable_for;
        $apartment->furnished = $request->furnished;
        $apartment->balcony_or_terrace = $request->balcony_or_terrace;
        $apartment->floor = $request->floor;
        $apartment->description = $request->description;
        $apartment->address_id = $request->address_id;

        $apartment->saveOrFail();

    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        $errors = $e->getErrors();

        return redirect()->route('apartments.create')
        ->withErrors($errors)
        ->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: You can look for error message in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file.

Comment: enable debugging and write the exact error here.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin @Sherif for some weird reason it is not firing an error for the log to write it. The last error I can see in the log file is about something else that I have already fixed it. My debug settings are `APP_DEBUG=true` and `'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

    'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),`

Comment: Add the following code to `public/index.php` file, right after `<?php`: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`. Now, what's the error and the stack trace?

Comment: @milz doesn't display anything, it does what it did earlier, takes me to a localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500 page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you [Download Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) if you haven't already. Fire it up and then trigger the store method again. Fiddler should tell you a great deal about your request and response:

[image: Fiddler Web Debugger]

On the left side, you have a list of requests and on the right, you have statistics and inspectors. Under **inspectors tab** you will see **WebView**. Click it and you will see the error generated by Laravel.

As for why it might be failing, check if the references are included properly. e.g:

`use App\Address;`

Comment: My webview is a white page with a title of No Response Data

Comment: Apache. Using wamp.